# How to specify custom boost directory to mgiza for moses?

Tags: shell, boost, moses, giza++

I downloaded mosesdecoder and compiled it successfully. Since there were a few boost errors with difference in versions, I installed boost in custom directory. I'm trying to install mgiza with custom boost install now.

In the moses additional resources page: http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.ExternalTools, it says:

Compiling MGIZA requires the Boost library. If your Boost library are in non-system directory, use the script

```
manual-compile/compile.sh
```

to compile MGIZA.

But simply running it from the mgiza/mgizapp directory gave a lot of **file not found** errors. I found out that I had to set the SRC_DIR and BOOST_ROOT directories correctly.

Once I set that, the code
But the initial line of the file, and all the subsequent compile files are saved in the $PWD, where I'm compiling the script from.

So which directory should I compile the script from in order to run moses end-to-end smoothly?

UPDATE: I already answered the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the location from which to compile

```
manual-compile/compile.sh
```

It is in the

```
mgiza/mgizapp/bin/
```

directory.

```
mgiza/mgizapp/bin$ ../manual-compile/compile.sh
```

Comment: Can you close the question?